# Read from Nlog config?

Tags: c#, config, nlog

I have the following NLOG target in the config file :

```
<target xsi:type="File" name="communicationTarget" fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log">
      <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout" includeAllProperties="true" maxRecursionLimit="10">
        <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" />
      </layout>
    </target>
```

Is there any way to read the maxRecursionLimit from C# code?

I have tried these :

```
LogManager.Configuration.AllTargets.Where(c => c.Name == "communicationTarget").FirstOrDefault();
LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName<FileTarget>("communicationTarget");
```

No maxRecursionLimit found so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
var myTarget = LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName("communicationTarget");
var myTarget = ((myTarget as NLog.Targets.Wrappers.WrapperTargetBase)?.WrappedTarget) ?? myTarget;
var jsonLayout = (myTarget as NLog.Targets.TargetWithLayout)?.Layout as NLog.Layouts.JsonLayout;
var maxRecursionLimit = jsonLayout?.MaxRecursionLimit;
```

This will also handle that you should activate `<targets async="true">`.

P.S. Have not tried to compile the code :)