# Set ValueFormatter for specific NLog instance?

Tags: c#, .net, nlog, formatter

I have 2 NLog instances where one needs a special ValueFormatter to serialize parameters. The ValueFormatter is set with this code :

```
NLog.Config.ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.ValueFormatter = new NLogValueFormatter();
```

So as you can see it will be applied to all loggers. I can´t find any property on the NLogger itself that might take a ValueFormatter.

Is there any way to bind this ValueFormatter just to one of the loggers?

Edit 1:

```
private CommunicationFormatProvider provider = new CommunicationFormatProvider();
        public void LogCommunication(string message, params object[] args)
        {
            _comLogger.Log(LogLevel.Info, provider,  message, args);
        }

public class CommunicationFormatProvider : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
{
    public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        strBuilder.Append(format);

        var myTarget = LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName("communicationTarget");
        myTarget = ((myTarget as NLog.Targets.Wrappers.WrapperTargetBase)?.WrappedTarget) ?? myTarget;
        var jsonLayout = (myTarget as NLog.Targets.TargetWithLayout)?.Layout as NLog.Layouts.JsonLayout;

        if (jsonLayout?.MaxRecursionLimit > 0)
            strBuilder.Append(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arg, new JsonSerializerSettings() { MaxDepth = jsonLayout?.MaxRecursionLimit }));

        return strBuilder.ToString();
    }

    object IFormatProvider.GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        return (formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter)) ? this : null;
    }
}
```

EDIT 2 :

```
public bool FormatValue(object value, string format, CaptureType captureType, IFormatProvider formatProvider, StringBuilder builder)
{

    if (value.GetType() == typeof(LogData))
        return false;

    builder.Append(format);

    try
    {

        var myTarget = LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName("communicationTarget");
        myTarget = ((myTarget as NLog.Targets.Wrappers.WrapperTargetBase)?.WrappedTarget) ?? myTarget;
        var jsonLayout = (myTarget as NLog.Targets.TargetWithLayout)?.Layout as NLog.Layouts.JsonLayout;

        if (jsonLayout?.MaxRecursionLimit > 0)
        {
            var jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { MaxDepth = jsonLayout?.MaxRecursionLimit };
            using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
            {
                using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriterMaxDepth(stringWriter, jsonSettings))
                    JsonSerializer.Create(jsonSettings).Serialize(jsonWriter, value);
                builder.Append(stringWriter.ToString());
            }
        }
        else
            value = null;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        builder.Append($"Failed to serlize {value.GetType()} : {ex.ToString()}");
    }
    return true;
}
```

JSON Serializer from here : [json.net limit maxdepth when serializing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29651433/json-net-limit-maxdepth-when-serializing)

Comment: Btw. `JsonSerializerSettings.MaxDepth` has no effect here. It is only used when "reading" not when "writing" like you are doing here. (So there is no need to perform any lookup in NLog-config)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NLog JsonLayout has two options that are important for serialization of LogEvent Properties:

- IncludeAllProperties
- MaxRecursionLimit

The default parameters is like this:

```
<layout type="JsonLayout" includeAllProperties="false" maxRecursionLimit="0">
   <attribute name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
   <attribute name="level" layout="${level}"/>
   <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" />
</layout>
```

But you can also activate inclusion of LogEvent properties like this:

```
<layout type="JsonLayout" includeAllProperties="true" maxRecursionLimit="10">
   <attribute name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
   <attribute name="level" layout="${level}"/>
   <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" />
</layout>
```

If you have a custom object like this:

```
public class Planet
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PlanetType { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;  // Will be called in normal message-formatting
    }
}
```

Then you can log the object like this:

```
logger.Info("Hello {World}", new Planet() { Name = "Earth", PlanetType = "Water Planet" });
```

The default JsonLayout will just include the default attributes, where `message`-attribute says `Hello Earth`.

But the JsonLayout with `includeAllProperties="true"` will include any additional LogEvent-properties. And will include `World`-propety that has been serialized fully.

The idea is that one should not care about how NLog Targets are configured when logging. It is the Logging-Rules + Target-Configuration + Layout-Configuration that decides how things should be finally written.

If you really want the object to be serialized into `${message}`, then you can also do this:

```
logger.Info("Hello {@World}", new Planet() { Name = "Earth", PlanetType = "Water Planet" });
```

If you don't want the LogEvent-properties mixed together with your default properties, then you can do this:

```
<layout type="JsonLayout" maxRecursionLimit="10">
   <attribute name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
   <attribute name="level" layout="${level}"/>
   <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" />
   <attribute name="properties" encode="false">
      <layout type="JsonLayout" includeAllProperties="true" maxRecursionLimit="10" />
   </attribute>
</layout>
```

If you have an object that mixes fields with properties, then you can tell NLog to perform custom reflection for that type:

```
LogManager.Setup().SetupSerialization(s =>
   s.RegisterObjectTransformation<GetEntityViewRequest>(obj => 
       return Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.FromObject(obj) // Lazy and slow
   )
);
```

Comment: Thanks, you wrote this in another post "NLog only serializes object-properties by default (when having proper getter). It ignores object-fields.", this is the reson I need to do a manual serlization of my objects. The code presented in my post above works as I need it to, it puts out the correct data but I understand that my approach is not intended.

So how do I customize the serialization with maxRecursionLimit from config for 1 specific Logger?

Comment: You make sure the special Logger hits a target that is configured to have `maxRecursionLimit= 1` and the layout for that target will do the reflection. You can customize the reflection for your own types (that contains Fields) like this: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging#customize-object-reflection

Comment: @Banshee So your question is not "how do I customize the serialization with maxRecursionLimit from config for 1 specific Logger?" but "How do I customize the serialization of objects with fields?"

Comment: @Banshee But yes this answer is pretty much me repeating https://stackoverflow.com/a/61104478/193178 . Any reason why you don't want to call NLog `RegisterObjectTransformation` ?

Comment: We got a big collection of diffrent complex objects containing fields, defaults and properties, GetEntityViewRequest is just one of many. all of them need to be serlized in a generic way where we can set how depth in runtime. This also need to be set just on the NLogger that handles communication and not our other NLoggers. I can make the selization in my first post to respect the depth from the config file but it sounds like this is a bad way to go. So what way will work best with our datamodel without manipulate it?
Note all our classes are DataContracts with DataMembers.

Comment: Well your attempt to respect the depth doesn't work, since MaxDepth only has effect when reading (not writing). Would it be possible to change all your objects to implement an internal interface, that has no properties? Then you could setup `RegisterObjectTransformation` for that interface and use `JToken.FromObject`. (If you don't fix all objects, then it is not disaster as those will not get their fields logged). Alternative then you can setup a special `RegisterObjectTransformation`, that handles `typeof(object)` and check for DataContract-attribute, with special fallback when not.

Comment: Will I have to add this interface to just the top class or every class that the top class will contain. If its the first only, then its possible but it will take alot of time, if its the second I would say that its not possible. Why is the NLogValueFormatter the wrong way to go? Check my Edit 2.

Comment: The interface just have to be on the top-class. But if you have a top-class then you don't need the interface, but use top-class-type when calling `RegisterObjectTransformation` and doing `JToken.FromObject`. Your `NLogValueFormatter` tries to perform the task of the logging framework, instead you should let the logging framework (and the NLog Layouts) handle the task.

Comment: What I need is 2 loggers, a basic(like it is today) and a communication. The comlogger have to be able to logg parameters at a given depth and it has to serialize the entire object, not only fields. Note that objects that is sent to the com logger might be sent to the basic logger as well and it should not be effected by the comlogger serialization rules. It have to be possible to turn on and off the comLogger parameter serialization in runtime, maybe by setting MaxDepth to 0.

Is RegisterObjectTransformation  still the best way to do this?

Comment: I dont have 1 top class, I have 300-500 that will contain objects of complex classes(also Datacontracts).

Comment: Oh well misunderstood your term "top class", thought you had a single one. Unless you loop over all types in the application and manually call RegisterObjectTransformation, then I'm starting to think you will have an easier time with make a pull-request for the NLog-project. Would it be possible for you to create a repository with a small sample application with 2 top-classes and what output you expect. I'm curious about this need to scan the NLog.config for the configuration of MaxRecursionLimit. Maybe the NLog JsonLayout can be changed to not call the JsonSerializer when MaxRecursionLimit=0

Comment: Btw. think this question and these answer and the comments have done completely off the track. Maybe this question should just be deleted, and the discussion can be continued in a GitHub-repository with your sample app.

Answer (score 0):

You could make sure that the object to be formatted inherits from `IFormattable`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iformattable

Then you can implement different formatters, where each Logger can choose their favorite when logging your special object.

Similar to this formatter that provides special formatting of Exception-objects:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/dev/src/NLog/Internal/ExceptionMessageFormatProvider.cs

Then just make sure to use the `IFormatProvider formatProvider`-parameter when calling methods on the Logger, when logging your special object.

I guess you could make own custom `NLogValueFormatter` perform the default formatting. And the Logger that needs special additional formattting can then provide its own custom `IFormatProvider`.

**Update Answer** Do you know that you can force NLog to automatically perform JsonSerialization of an object using the message-template:

This will perform the default ToString-operation:

`logger.Info("Hello {World}", new { Name = "Earth", Type = "Water Planet" });`

This will signal that the object is safe for reflection (Notice the `@`):

`logger.Info("Hello {@World}", new { Name = "Earth", Type = "Water Planet" });`

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging

Comment: Thanks, I have created a IFormatProvider implementation that is provided when calling the ILogger.Log(LogLevel, IFormatProvider, string object[]) but the Format is never triggered? Pleas, see edit.

Comment: Think you have to show some more code. How do you pass the object that implements ICustomFormatter to the Logger? Does you custom-object implement `IFormattable` ?

Comment: @Banshee Btw. the code you have implemented looks really strange (Lookup of target-configuration inside formatter). Think you should create a new question where you ask how to reach the final goal. Think you are taking a very strange road to the destination, and fighting obstacles that you should not be fighting.

Comment: By default only time, operation and client will be logged to disk but I need to be able to set in runtime if parameters are to be added and how depth they should be serlized. Becouse it needs to be in runtime the settings need to be read each time. I suppose I could fix so its only read once per call but that is not the important part right now. At this point I just need a rout where I can point out that this specific logger will format its output according to a specific method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61226373/read-from-nlog-config

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61103712/how-to-serialize-object-fields-with-nlog

Comment: I know that I have replied to these questions, and surprised that we have ended up here. Let me write another answer, that tries to solve the entire problem.